# How to simulate BatchWriteItem fail in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I create a controlled `BatchWriteItem` fail in DynamoDB?

Basically, I want to have a way of simulating failure (break BatchWriteItem on purpose) in DynamoDB so I can make sure the logic that takes `UnprocessedItems` in `response` is working correctly.

From documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

> Typically, you would call BatchWriteItem in a loop. Each iteration
>   would check for unprocessed items and submit a new BatchWriteItem
>   request with those unprocessed items until all items have been
>   processed.

Below are two similar solutions discussed that use do-while loop and callback:

**JAVA with do-while:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html

**NODE with callback:**

[How to handle UnprocessedItems using AWS JavaScript SDK (dynamoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882002/how-to-handle-unprocesseditems-using-aws-javascript-sdk-dynamodb)

**How to prepare a *"broken"* BatchWriteItem request in order to test this?**

Can DynamoDB end up in *infinite* loop? i.e. `BatchWriteItem` returns `UnprocessedItems`, the code takes `UnprocessedItems` and calls `BatchWriteItem` and returns `UnprocessedItems` again and again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get failed `BatchWriteItem` when due to throttling on the individual tables. So if you want to test in this case, you must make your DynamoDB tables become throttling. Steps:

1. Calculate [Capacity write Unit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html) of your DynamoDB table
2. Implement a function which writes too many into DynamoDB and make it reach maximum Capacity Write Unit.
3. Run your function `BatchWriteItem`. You will be able to get `UnprocessedItems` because your DynamoDb are throttling.

Comment: I tried this by setting the WCU on my table to 1. All I got instead was the response: `{"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ProvisionedThroughputExceededException","message":"The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API."}`. When requests did go through, I still got `{"UnprocessedItems": {} }`.

Comment: I also have the same issue, no UnprocessedItems, wonder if there is another way?